# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare opencart

Tags: opencart

Хэлп. Вылезает ошибка при попытке зайти в админку опенкарта в `extension`. У данной темы там модули находятся для редактирования. Перед этим менялись только стили в css файлах и ошибки не было.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare r1895845() (previously declared in
>   /home/smartmpro/balloons74.ru/docs/admin/language/en-gb/extension/extension/feed.php:1)
>   in
>   /home/smartmpro/balloons74.ru/docs/admin/language/en-gb/extension/extension/feed.php
>   on line 1

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите, что у вас в файле feed.php Там должны быть только переменные локализации вида $_['something'] = 'something'; Если обнаружите функции или что-то подобное - \x6A\x6F\x69\x6E то ваш шаблон хакнутый.

Comment: этого никак не исправить?

Comment: Если там были такие строки, то скорее всего шаблон заражённый. Преднамеренно  распространителем или через дыры хоста. В любом случае, если будет повторение ситуации (99%) - обратитесь к спецам или меняйте шаблон. Вам повезло, что бекдор выбрал именно файл локализации и выскочила ошибка. Иначе вы бы не догадывалитсь о его существовании вплоть до бана вашего сайта поисковиками/хостом.